# BlockingIOError exception ignored; should I be concerned?

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I'm writing a script that is 20,000 tasks that each make a subprocess call and a TCP call or two.  To make this not take all day, I'm using Python's new `asyncio`.

However, I'm concerned about these errors Python prints out while my script runs:

```
Exception ignored when trying to write to the signal wakeup fd:
BlockingIOError: [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable
```

It will print a bunch of them, but not raise any exceptions.  I did get `OSError`s about `Too many open files` and dropped connections with the servers before, but I used semaphores to only allow 100 connections to each server at a time and only 700 connections total.

Since Python's not raising any exceptions, I can't catch the errors.  But it doesn't *seem* to affect the script.

**Are these errors something I should be concerned about?**  If so, what do I need to do to get rid of them?  If not, how do I get rid of them so they're not in my program's output?

Also, if these errors are serious, why does Python ignore them instead of raising an exception?

Comment: I would be worried about that exception. The signal wakeup fd is used by asyncio so the event loop is woken up on signal; the fd is a pipe and the signal handler writes a single byte to the pipe. Not being able to do so points to a potentially serious starvation of the system resources in the process. Try finding out what is eating your file descriptors and either increase the max allowed number of open files for the process, or further reduce the max number of open connections in your program.

Comment: @user4815162342 that is concerning. According to `ulimit -a`, my file limit is 1024, and by repeatedly running `ls -l /proc/PID/fd | wc -l`, the highest number of files open I get is 692.  I'm nowhere near the max open files for the system

Comment: Maybe you're tripping on some other limit? Or maybe it's an asyncio issue where the process is receiving a lot of signals and asyncio is not clearing the pipe (by reading the byte), which then fills up. It's hard to tell without further debugging.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like the limiting factor is running lots of short-lived `subprocess`es.  From the [Python bug tracker](https://bugs.python.org/issue21595):

> "Exception ignored when trying to write to the signal wakeup fd" message comes from the signal handler in Modules/signalmodule.c. The problem is that Python gets a lot of SIGCHLD signals (the test scripts creates +300 processes per second on my computer). The producer (signal handler writing the signal number into the "self" pipe) is faster than the consumer (BaseSelectorEventLoop._read_from_self callback).
>
> With the patch, I start getting messages with 140 concurrent processes, which is much better :-) IMO more than 100 concurrent processes is crazy, don't do that at home :-) I mean processes with a very short lifetime. The limit is the number of SIGCHLD per second, so the number of processes which end at the same second.

I changed my code to restrict how many `create_subprocess_exec`es could run at once.  I stopped seeing the errors when I got below 35, though I'll probably set it to 20 just to be sure.  Your mileage may vary.

```
async def myTask(stuff, semaphore, loop):
    with semaphore:
        process = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec('short_program', loop=loop)

def taskRunner(stuffs):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    semaphore = asyncio.Semaphore(20)  # limit how many can run at a time
    tasks = [
        asyncio.ensure_future(myTask(semaphore, loop))
        for i in range(20000)
    ]
    loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*tasks))
    loop.close()
```

Comment: Good dig! Did you file a report in the bug tracker? The original [issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue21595) was supposed to be fixed years ago, yet obviously the problem remains.

Comment: @user4815162342 The issue does say `The patch doesn't solve completly the issue.`  Should I still file a report?

Comment: I think you should. The previous issue is four years old, and *closed*, so it is very unlikely that anyone is working on it. It would be especially useful if you could provide a test case to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Maybe it's off topic but, as a remind, `asyncio.Semaphore` in the snippet should be use with `async with`.